# Successful change pop-up not showing

Tags: drupal

Normally when you do something like add a membership to someone, send them an email, save a page, etc, CiviCRM does a little pop-up towards the right corner that lets you know it was successful. We just upgraded to the latest version and it's no longer popping that up? Did something change that I need to account for, like a setting? Thanks. It's Drupal 7 + Civi 5.12.3

Honestly, not sure how to tag this one...

Comment: You've probably done this ... but have you cleared all caches on civi/drupal and locally in your browser?

Comment: Yup, I did. But it looks like it corrected itself, as it's working again today? Either that, or the extension to normalize data was causing it. That was the only change I made today (to turn it back off). Thanks!